# Is rowversion not a valid data type in SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: timestamp, sql-server-2008-r2, rowversion

Is `rowversion` not a valid data type in Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2?

---

### Bonus Chatter

i'm trying to add a `rowversion` column to a table:

[image]

But when i try to leave the "Data Type" column, SQL Server Management Studio complains

> Invalid data type.

[image]

and insists that i pick a different data type:

[image]

How do i make a column `rowversion` when `rowversion` is not a valid data type?

---

### Bonus Viewing

[image]

### Bonus Reading

> ### [rowversion (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx)
>
> **timestamp** is the synonym for the **rowversion** data type and is subject to the behavior of data type synonyms. In DDL statements, use **rowversion** instead of **timestamp** wherever possible. For more information, [see Data Type Synonyms (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177566.aspx).
>
> The **timestamp** syntax is deprecated. This feature will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature.

Additional Bonus Chatter

Comment: I'm having this same issue in SSMS 2012. I do not see rowversion data type in the designer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL Server 2008 R2 accepts ROWVERSION as datatype for columns in CREATE TABLE statements, however the SSMS seems to lag behind and the designer refuses to accept the input.

Comment: *You think you are wise, Mithrandir. Yet for all your subtleties, you have not wisdom. Do you think the eyes of Microsoft are blind?*  Also /facepalm at Microsoft (http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/352733/ssms-should-not-given-an-error-when-newsequentialid-used-as-a-default-value-or-binding)

Comment: I know this is old but if anyone else comes here looking for an answer, however, I just wanted to leave a comment about what happens if you now go into the table via design view after creating it via TSQL statements.... The IDE will auto convert the column back to `timestamp` data type. No warnings no errors, just an auto convert.

Answer (score 5):

If it's any help, the Visual Studio 2012 SQL Server Object Explorer designer does have the rowversion option (even though the VS 2012 Server Explorer Data Connections designer doesn't either).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

"The timestamp syntax is deprecated. This feature will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. "
so i think timestamp =rowversion .so you dont need rowversion.